# How to get Rich Text Control in a VBA Form of Microsoft Word 365

Tags: vba, ms-word, rich-text-editor, richtext

In Microsoft Word 365 I am trying to create a VBA Form with a Rich Text Control, where on loading the form I would like to show the selected content (may contain formatted text like bold, italic etc) of the document in the Rich Text Control. Could you please help?

In older version of Microsoft Word I have used "Microsoft Rich Text Control 6.0". But I dont see it with the latest version.

The closest control I find is MSREdit. Unfortunately there seems to be no documentation on how to make use of it. It has a property called ".TextRTF", but I don't know how to use it to get the content into it.

Any help in this regard would be great. It can be either suggesting the right Rich Text Control or guiding me to make use of MSREDit.

Comment: It is still there in additional ActiveX (right click in the toolbox) but you can not insert it on the form because MS declared it as unsafe. (Since a long time as far as I know) :-(

Comment: Thanks. Is there any URL where I can see that MS has made such declaration that its unsafe?

Comment: When you add the Control to your toolbox and then try to put it on your userform there will be a message (it is not trusted or something like this). 
An old kb from microsoft does not exist anymore.
Perhaps there are some ways to use it but these ocx will anyway will not work with Excel 64 bit. 
You may try to set the Active X in Trustcenter to different level and check again but I will not try this. (And other users will not do this)

Comment: Thanks a lot. That helps. By the way, I managed to get that article from internet archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20090330025538/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/838010

Comment: Thanks for the link.
But if you need more power in the UI I would recommend Excel-DNA. You can create an Add-In in the language of your choice (vb.net, c#.net) and use whatever dialog type you like (winform or wpf) And there you have rich text controls without bothering.